# Замена первого элемента найденного в строке на первый элемент массива и т.д. PHP

Tags: php

Есть строка следующего содержания: "произвольный текст img произвольный текст img". И есть массив значений array = [img,img]. Как заменить первую картинку найденную в тексте на первый элемент массива и т.д

Comment: Можете дать нормальный пример этой строки? в каком смысле первую "картинку"?

Comment: Исправил. Не заметил что редактор обрезал написанное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'произвольный текст img произвольный текст img';
$format = str_replace('img', '%s', $str);

$replacement = ['Ссылка 1', 'Ссылка 2'];

$result = vsprintf($format, $replacement);

echo $result;
```

Результат работы скрипта http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/846b2d4a9c68adc4f74e4cf90a7887c3ab101cda

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это именно то, что я искал)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'произвольный текст img произвольный текст img';

$replacement = ['Ссылка 1', 'Ссылка 2'];

$result = preg_replace(
    array_fill(0, count($replacement), '/img/'), 
    $replacement, 
    $str,
    1
);

echo $result;
```

Comment: код не работает оба img заменяются на "Ссылка 1"

Comment: сорян, думал одно, писал другое )